# 2 websites login timeout

Tags: asp.net

I have 2 websites running on the same server and they are both using forms authentication, but when I login to one, the other times out...

Why is that hapenning?

NOTE:
They are separate websites and need different logins.

Thanks

Comment: how do you manage the forms authentication in both websites ?

Comment: You probably mix up the database, the one with the other. Do you have set on web.config diferent key names for the app - or probably have the same web.config for both ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I fixed the problem by adding a name attribute to the forms authentication in the web.config